# EasyMapping library: can i get data for 1 object from different dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have some json and i need get objects "Hobby" to CoreData. Can i get with EasyMapping 1 object from main dictionary and nested dictionary? 
For 1 object with this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * parent_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * hobby_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * user_id;
```

This is my JSON:

```
userHobby =     (
                {
            hobby =             {
                id = 3838;
                name = Xbox360;
                "parent_id" = 7;
            };
            "hobby_id" = 3838;
            "user_id" = 58;
        },
                {
            hobby =             {
                id = 1025;
                name = "Funk Music";
                "parent_id" = 1;
            };
            "hobby_id" = 1025;
            "user_id" = 58;
        },
                {
            hobby =             {
                id = 19855;
                name = Snowboarding;
                "parent_id" = 4;
            };
            "hobby_id" = 19855;
            "user_id" = 58;
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I get answer for my question. It can do with KVO.
All code:

```
+ (EKManagedObjectMapping *)userProfileHobbyMapping {
    return [EKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityName:NSStringFromClass([NBUserProfileHobby class])
                                              withBlock:^(EKManagedObjectMapping *mapping) {

           [mapping mapPropertiesFromDictionary:@{@"hobbyID" : @"id"}];
           [mapping mapPropertiesFromArray:@[@"hobby_id", @"user_id"]];
           [mapping mapKeyPath:@"hobby.id" toProperty:@"hobby_id"];
           [mapping mapKeyPath:@"hobby.name" toProperty:@"name"];
           [mapping mapKeyPath:@"hobby.user_id" toProperty:@"user_id"];


     }];
}
```